# Como girar la pantalla sin que se oculten los iconos?

Tags: java, android

Cómo puedo hacer para que al girar la pantalla los iconos de la `Toolbar` no se oculten? (Estoy programando en Android con Java)..

Answer (score 0):

Una forma para evitar la reconstrucción de la `Activity`, es definir la siguiente propiedad dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, dentro de `<activity`:

```
 <activity
            ...
            ...
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```